# How to get list elements from manytomany field in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Following Django REST framework [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) I can't get dict nested fields when posting from test client.

My models are:

```
class ClassificationOfDiseases(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    abbreviated_description = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.abbreviated_description

class Group(models.Model):
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, related_name='groups')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    inclusion_criteria = \
        models.ManyToManyField(ClassificationOfDiseases, blank=True)
    protocol_component = models.ForeignKey(
        ProtocolComponent, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

The serializers for that models are:

```
class ClassificationOfDiseasesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClassificationOfDiseases
        fields = ('code',)


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    experiment = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='experiment.title')
    inclusion_criteria = ClassificationOfDiseasesSerializer(many=True,
                                                            read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'experiment',
                  'inclusion_criteria')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        group = Group.objects.create(experiment=validated_data['experiment'],
                                     title=validated_data['title'],
                                     description=validated_data['description'])
        if 'inclusion_criteria' in self.initial_data:
            inclusion_criteria = self.initial_data['inclusion_criteria']
            print(inclusion_criteria)  # DEBUG
            print(self.initial_data)  # DEBUG
            for criteria in inclusion_criteria:
                classification_of_diseases = \
                    ClassificationOfDiseases.objects.filter(
                        code=criteria['code']
                    )
                if classification_of_diseases:
                    group.inclusion_criteria.add(
                        classification_of_diseases.first()
                    )
        return group
```

And, the test posts data to the API as follows:

```
def test_POSTing_new_group_adds_pre_existent_classification_of_diseases(self):
    owner = User.objects.get(username='lab1')
    experiment = Experiment.objects.get(nes_id=1, owner=owner)
    self.client.login(username=owner.username, password='nep-lab1')
    list_url = reverse('api_experiment_groups-list',
                       kwargs={'experiment_nes_id': experiment.nes_id})
    response = self.client.post(
        list_url,
        {
            'title': 'A title',
            'description': 'A description',
            # we post inclusion_criteria's that exists in
            # ClassificationOfDiseases table (this table is
            # pre-populated in db)
            'inclusion_criteria': [
                {'code': 'A00'}, {'code': 'A1782'}, {'code': 'A3681'},
                {'code': 'A74'}
            ]
        }
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    self.client.logout()
    new_group = Group.objects.last()
    for inclusion_criteria in new_group.inclusion_criteria_set:
        self.assertEqual(inclusion_criteria,
                         ClassificationOfDiseases.objects.get(
                             code=inclusion_criteria))
```

The two lines with `#DEBUG` in `GroupSerializer.create()` method prints `inclusion_criteria` and `self.initial_data` in terminal. The output is, respectively:

```
{'code': 'A74'}   # print(inclusion_criteria)
<QueryDict: {'inclusion_criteria': ["{'code': 'A00'}", "{'code': 'A1782'}", "{'code': 'A3681'}", "{'code': 'A74'}"], 'title': ['A title'], 'description': ['A description']}>  # print(self.initial_data)
```

So, why `self.initial_data['inclusion_criteria']` is getting only the last term (`{'code': 'AY4'}`) instead all of them, if `self.initial_data` QueryDict has `'inclusion_criteria': ["{'code': 'A00'}", "{'code': 'A1782'}", "{'code': 'A3681'}", "{'code': 'A74'}"]` with all dict elements?

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the missing part. It was a matter of choosing the correct data type when posting nested objects using APITestCase class.

If you post without specifying the format of data, the `APITestCase.client.post` method you post a QueryDict, that what I've got in the `print(inclusion_criteria)` statement.

```
<QueryDict: {'inclusion_criteria': ["{'code': 'A00'}", "{'code': 'A1782'}", "{'code': 'A3681'}", "{'code': 'A74'}"], 'title': ['A title'], 'description': ['A description']}>
```

We need to post the data in `json` format, so we pass `format=json` as the third parameter to `APITestCase.client.post` method.

So, we use:

```
response = self.client.post(
            list_url,
            {
                'title': 'A title',
                'description': 'A description',
                'inclusion_criteria': [
                    {'code': 'A00'}, {'code': 'A1782'}, {'code': 'A3681'},
                    {'code': 'A74'}
                ]
            }, format='json'
        )
```

Thanks to this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271754/drf-test-client-unable-to-post-list-of-json).